# Can you modify the web.config and NOT restart the ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, appdomain, application-pool, application-restart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent an ASP.NET application restarting when the web.config is modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613824/how-to-prevent-an-asp-net-application-restarting-when-the-web-config-is-modified)

Was just thinking about uptime.  Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the setting stored there should be moved somewhere else if uptime is your concern.  What is it you're changing?  Does it have to be in web.config?

Comment: VTC for duplication. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613824/how-to-prevent-an-asp-net-application-restarting-when-the-web-config-is-modified

Comment: There are more things to consider than just the asp.net application restarting when changing you web.config on the fly...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613824/how-to-prevent-an-asp-net-application-restarting-when-the-web-config-is-modified/629876#629876).

However, it is not a good idea.
Until ASP.Net restarts the AppDomain, it will not look at `web.config`.
If you change `web.config`, your changes will have no effect until the AppDomain is restarted.

Answer (score 10):

You can create an external settings file and then reference it in your web.config. You will need to change the attribute "restartOnExternalChanges" to false in your machine.config file.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228057.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a duplicate IIS container on a different ip address / hostname. Make your modification to the new version and then swap the ip's over. It gets rid of the compile time of the application restart. However, if you rely on in-proc session it'll all go wrong for any current users anyway.

Safest option is to allow it to restart and just pick a good time to do it. You can also set compilation batch = false. This can also speed up the compile time in critical systems.

Answer (score 0):

The application pool will reset when you modify the wed.config and you will lose any session information stored on the server.

Comment: @downvoter: Umm ok..so you don't think the resetting the application pool is a bad thing?