# Change in aspx or web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, .net-3.5

I have read somewhere that changing aspx file or web.config restart application pool and result in session loss. Some e-commerce store are using XML files instead of putting data in web.config.

Please let me know if aspx or web.config really restart application pool or any component of IIS which can cause disturbance for users. Also, if there is any way to work around it(Would AppDomain work)?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it will restart the application. Why do you need a workaround? If you have configuration that the changing of should not cause a restart, just don't store it in web.config. Please clarify what you are actually trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

Modifications on root web.config and bin folder will restart your pool.

Aspx files (*.aspx) modifications do not restart your pool.

However, this is editable, see this post [Can you modify the web.config and NOT restart the ASP.NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155123/can-you-modify-the-web-config-and-not-restart-the-asp-net-application)