# Difference between using aspnet_regiis.exe and SectionInformation.ProtectSection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, aspnet-regiis.exe

I would like to have a custom configuration section encrypted and in a separate file.

Using `aspnet_regiis` requires some extra steps with a custom configuration section (see this question: [Using ASPNet_Regiis to encrypt custom configuration section - can you do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786661/using-aspnet-regiis-to-encrypt-custom-configuration-section-can-you-do-it)), so it could maybe be more practical if I used a custom program and SectionInformation.ProtectSection.

Is there a difference between using aspnet_regiis.exe and SectionInformation.ProtectSection, or do they both use the same mechanism to encrypt the config file?